# Select Name is equal of a PDO Array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Example from comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g1Zz.png

I have code that goes like

```
$data = $info->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row): ?>

<input data-open="SelectModal" type="text" placeholder="<?=$row["Name"]?>" name="<?=$row["Number"]?>">
```

What I need is to be able to `UPDATE` based on that `name="number"`, which changes. Something like this. This is in a separate area of the page.

```
$Number = 
$input = $db->prepare("UPDATE MockUp SET `Name` = ? WHERE `Number` = ?");
$input->execute(array($name,$Number));
```

What is the usual solution for this?

Comment: WHERE `Number` = '".$_POST['Number']."' won't work? Of course this isn't a production line because it's vulnerable, but will it not work? I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: Most Probably, you would need to use ajax to do this because PHP is server side while what you want to do is client side - thing ...

Comment: Question doesn't really make sense. You can't look up something that hasn't been submitted yet

Comment: @Wicked ... where does `$_POST` come in this context .. ? Correct me if I am wrong ...

Comment: @Wicked Nah, the array changes the name, so when if I did $_POST['Number'] it would look for Number, no?

Comment: @Saitama I believe he is trying to update based on an input from another page. What I got from it was he is trying to UPDATE where the name of the input = said number.

Comment: @charlietfl I have an input textbox. In my database I have numbers let's say 1-5 that all correspond to a name. When I use the first array, it put's them numbers in the name field. So with my 1-5 example it would put out 5 input boxes all labeled with different numbers.

I want to update my database where that specific number for the box is the where to update, like an ID.

Comment: use array names for  inputs ... `name="myInputName[<?=$row["Number"]?>]"` then you have them in array `myInputName` when submitted and can loop over each one and get row number

Comment: While @charlietfl is correct in the method to do it, you are vulnerable to an attack. In a way. The person can change that value of myInputName to change entries that don't belong to him. You should ensure that the ID's he/she is changing belong to him/her.

Comment: @charlietfl how would I get that for the prepared statement? I don't have that looped.

Comment: Well since they each are from different rows you have to loop them when they get submitted...unless you are only updating individual rows at a time using ajax for example

Comment: @charlietfl what do I do for the `UPDATE` though?