# Get ID of an element from a loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Example:

[image]

I posted about this yesterday but I feel as if I was unclear on what I was looking for. I have a loop that essentially generates placeholder input text boxes. Each get their own id and name from the loop  `id="$row['number']` `name="$row['number']`.

When I click a button, I want to perform an update.

```
$SendName = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET Name = ? WHERE Number = ?");
```

Since the number is looped, I can't simply do something like `$Number=$_POST['Number']`

So now that I think I made a more clear and simple post, what is a solution? Thanks.

Comment: If you have posted this yesterday kindly update that one and refrain from posting similar question

Comment: @guradio I'm fairly certain it would never get answered if I didn't make a new post. Since last night it hasn't gotten any views and two answers have been removed. What would you suggest for next time?

Comment: i would assume you didnt include all the relevant code that is needed to replicate your problem that is why it is hard for people to give suggestion on how to solve your problem. I suggest that you ***always*** include all relevant code when asking question. Just like what you are asking now I cant see the loop in the question but the title says you have one.

Comment: @guradio posting more code only made the confusion worse yesterday. I'm just asking how I can update on a looped id/name.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678832/select-name-is-equal-of-a-pdo-array

Comment: i am not sure what you need from the looks of it i think `charlietfl` provided a good answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get all inputs in form with jQuery

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $("#formID input").each(function(){
        var input = $(this); // input element
        var name = input.attr("name"); // name of the input
        var id = input.attr("id"); // id of the input
    });
});
```

and then just store names in the array and pass it to PHP with AJAX.